# how to filter user by user's group display name in wso2 5.7.0 using SCIM 2.0 expression?

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I'd like to using SCIM 2.0 expression to filter user by user's group display name in WSO2 5.7.0. why it's NOT work using `groups.display co FOTA_Manager`? Fortunately I can work it around using `roles.default co FOTA_Manager`, but I don't know the difference of roles and groups in WSO2.

Here're the users to filter from.

   `"roles": [{
   "type": "default",
   "value": "FOTA_Manager,Internal/everyone"
  }],
  "name": {
   "givenName": "string",
   "familyName": "string"
  },
  "active": true,
  "groups": [{
   "display": "FOTA_Manager",
   "value": "b28d5fa1-dda7-4f7d-a66e-ccafb9f97e44"
  }]`

Answer (score 0):

Please use,  filter=displayName+co+FOTA_Manager  or filter=displayName+eq+FOTA_Manager

```
curl -v -k --user admin:admin 'https://localhost:9443/scim2/Groups?filter=displayName+co+manager'
```

You can refer our official documentation for more details https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/apidocs/SCIM2-endpoints/#!/operations#GroupsEndpoint#getGroup